# Do not switch tab on tab click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I want to call a function whenever user clicks on tab, and if that function returns false i want to stay on the same tab, else move to tab which was pressed by the user.

I am binding an event here on tab switch.

```
$(".selector").tabs();
$(".selector").bind("tabsactivate", function(event, ui) {
  alert('oldTab = ' + ui.oldTab.index());
  alert('newTab = ' + ui.newTab.index());
  if (some_condition)
    console.log("EQUAL");
  else {
    BootstrapDialog.confirm({
      title: 'WARNING',
      message: 'You have not saved the changes.Do you want to save it?.',
      type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
      draggable: true,
      callback: function(result) {

        //if user presses ok, then i want to stay on the previous tab else move to the tab pressed 

        if (result) {
          //stay on the same tab

          $(".selector").tabs("option", "active", ui.oldTab.index());

        } else
        //moved to pressed tab
      }
    });
  }
}
});
```

But when i do this way, the problem is, because of this `$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", index );`  this bind event is triggered again.And this confirmation dialog box comes up again. I dont want this `bind` event to execute again, is there any other way to **stay on the earlier tab** or how to avoid this scenario?

Comment: the simplest way would be set some boolean flag before your `$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active"` statement and check it on very first line within `$(".selector").bind("tabsactivate", function (event, ui) {`. If it is set then make it `false` and `return` from event handler

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selector').on('click',function(){
    if (flag == false) {
        $(this).removeClass('active in') ;                 
        return false;
    }
})
```